# How to create multiple row header and merge it with other columns in GridView using 2 datatables

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

**I want to display data from 2 tables with multiple row header**
**Below image shows the 2 tables with result**
[image]

**From above resulted image i want to display in front end like shown below**
[image]

**in Trans column i need a 163 and 56 as data instead of 137 and 43**

Comment: Is our grid view a datagridview??

Comment: Yes bro it is a datagridview @Anil